# What is the use of using Vector databases over Pandas Dataframes?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pandas, dataframe, vector-database

My question is why can't we use a pandas dataframe to do all the data retrieval? Can someone give reasons apart from the fact that databases has the persistence of Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You touched on one part, which is that vector dBs are used to store persistent data, whereas pandas is strictly in memory while a program is running (but of course you can save and restore to and from .csvs or other formats). The bigger thing is the use case: for something like Retrieval Augmented Generation, you want to generate embeddings for a bunch of documents and store them somewhere, and then later on query that datastore. Vector dBs allow you to return results that match the query embedding based on similarity (cosine or other). Of course, you can do all of this without using a vector dB, but it certainly simplifies the storage and retrieval and update of your data store, and fits nicely with RAG and other use cases.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.